# html/css how to calculate margin-top to be 100vh - block height

Tags: html, css

A html section (content + top margin) should take up whole viewport. 
There is no other margins except top. Section is not going to have much content in it
This could be achieved by setting something like

```
height:60vh
margin-top:40vh
```

But the problem is, section height may change due to viewport width change or content amount
So i need some solution for margin to be calculated automatically. Something like margin-top: 100vh-height.

Context
there is bunch of sections directly in body that are located vertically, some of them should be like i described ( a horizontal line that takes 1/3 - 2/3 of vp height, some of them take 100vh and don't have a vertical margins.  
body have a

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
```

on it

Notes
I know that it is possible to do by
1) Wrapping everything in unnecessary level of divs
 
2) Using js
But I want to avoid those solutions and keep html as minimalistic as possible. So I need a way to calculate margin or other changes to css to achieve this (suggestions about changing approach to layout in general (but only css) are welcome) 
[clarifying image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5n3m.png)

```css
body {  display:flex;  flex-direction:column;}
body > section {  min-height:vh;  margin:0; background-color: #e13652;}
.sectionHorizontal { min-height:10em; margin-top:60vh; }
```

```html
<section class="sectionHorizontal">
    <p> horizontal section with some content, it should take part of a viewport and the rest should be filled by margin  </p>
</section>
<section>
    <p> another section. but this one takes 100% of viewport</p>
</section>
<section class="sectionHorizontal">
    <p> another horizontal section, that have more content and is higher than the first one</p>
</section>
```

More notes
I'm asking not how to make a section 100vh but how to make section + empty space before it =100vh. Or how to move stuff inside it
 
I wanted to keep example as simple as possible, but actually section has background and itself may contain not only one

but several different elements that have their own positioning

Comment: `margin-top: calc(100vh - 40px)`

Comment: @fubar this works properly only in case when section height == 40px, but as I've mentioned section height isn't known in advance. Also I've tried calc(100vh-100%) but it seams that it is 100% of parent, which is body, but not 100% of the section

Comment: Can you add a working example to your question to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Yeah, that image may look simple to you, as you understand the problem. But it doesn't help clarify anything for me.

Comment: @fubar I've added some code. Hope that that'l clarify

Comment: Do you just want the sections anchored to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @fubar no, that would be easy to achieve, but unfortunately it have to be a part of layout

Comment: _"Wrapping everything in unnecessary level of divs"_ - yeah, about _one_ ((min-)height 100vh, flex, single flex child aligned to the end) ... if that already exceeds the acceptable, then you are one tough customer ....

Comment: @CBroe I guess I am. The idea is to keep html as clean as possible, so that there would be tags that are needed to structure information. Not to effect how it is displayed. And I have managed to make everything else except this little problem in this fashion

Comment: Well, pragmatism over practicality can't be helped sometimes ...

Comment: _"The idea is to keep html as clean as possible, so that there would be tags that are needed to structure information. Not to effect how it is displayed."_ - great, be consistent then and also do away with `class="sectionHorizontal"` - because that is presentation, not about the structure of the information :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure if I understand your problem correctly or not, but have a look at the following. If you can clarify further, that'd be helpful.

```css
section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

section.horizontal {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<section class="horizontal">
    <p> horizontal section with some content, it should take part of a viewport and the rest should be filled by margin  </p>
</section>

<section>
    <p> another section. but this one takes 100% of viewport</p>
</section>

<section class="horizontal">
    <p> another horizontal section, that have more content and is higher than the first one</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Not exactly, this makes all sections to take 100% of space, and i need some sections height to depend on their content. and their margin-top to be = 100vh - section height. which is < 100% if section height is > 0. or some other way to make so that section+empty space before it would be = 100vh. I do not know what else to add

Comment: In that case, I think CBroe's suggestion is the simplest you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example code this would be the only way possible without changing the html.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

section {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  height: 0;
}

section p {
  background: #ccc;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

section:not(.sectionHorizontal) p {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="sectionHorizontal">
    <p> horizontal section with some content, it should take part of a viewport and the rest should be filled by margin  </p>
</section>
<section>
    <p> another section. but this one takes 100% of viewport</p>
</section>
<section class="sectionHorizontal">
    <p> another horizontal section, that have more content and is higher than the first one</p>
</section>
```